# AddClass to group without removing it from similar groups

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I've built a group of buttons that work like radio buttons. When you click on a button inside a given group the radio is selected and a class should be added to the button selected in that group.

The radios are working fine but my class isn't isolated to the button group - it's only adding the class to the button clicked in the selected group. I'm trying to keep the class on the button clicked inside that group.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.radio-group .radio-btn .btn').click(function () {
    $('.radio-group .radio-btn .btn').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcx0f8xc/

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
$('.radio-group .radio-btn .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.btn-primary').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

but just to remind you that the click over the `'<p>'` element changes the color but the radio button does not get checked.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek but forgive me as I probably didn't explain this very well. I want to remove the class from every button except for the one selected. Your solution doesn't remove the class after I click a new one.

Comment: Its total opposite to your question - but in that case your solution is working fine. It removes the class from every button (in Group 1 and Group 2) and adding the class to currently selected radio button. Correct me if i wrongly understood.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.radio-group .radio-btn .btn').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary');
  $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to use parent() to find the btn...use as

```
$('.radio-group .radio-btn .btn').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary');
  $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54gv0sn2/)

My internet is lagging ..I think some one posted the same beforehand